# Publish in SSDT is not atomic?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I've ignore this up 'til now because I simply couldn't believe that it was true. But I've just tried several times, and I'm seeing that ssdt Publish is not atomic: if something goes wrong in the middle, the previous changes are not undone.

Note that this relates specifically to pre- and post-build script. That is, if my post-build script fails, all the DDL stuff remains.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I was going to comment that DDL cannot be rolled back, but apparently in SQL Server it can be. You learn something new every day! :)

Comment: That sounds right to me. The DDL changes are wrapped in one transaction (by default). If anything throws an error along the way, that will roll back. If your post-deploy scripts fail, they only have the handling you built for them and are handled separately from the DDL changes.

Comment: Good point, Peter. "Post-build" does imply a finished build, and it's not finished until you commit your database changes.

Comment: @PeterSchott, so maybe I should start my own transaction in the pre-build and commit in post? Or is that going a bit too far?

Comment: You could definitely try that, but I generally expect my changes to be an all or nothing deal. What sort of changes are you putting in a post-build script that you'd want to avoid running? If they're just items that depend on certain objects, you can always check for them first. Otherwise, I'd go through some test runs to make sure this works well before releasing to production.

Comment: @PeterSchott, I just like to be prepared for the unexpected. Of course I can test the scripts before releasing to production, but if there is just a tiny variation in production that screws up one of my scripts, I would rather like to not have everything in a 'half-cooked' state.

Comment: Tentatively, you could alter your extended properties of some table to include a version number. If that doesn't increment appropriately, don't run your post-deploy scripts.